# blit minimal example fails to keep plot visible

Tags: matplotlib, animation, blit

I am trying to get the Python maplotlib, **Faster rendering by using blotting - Minimal example** to work correctly.

[Faster rendering by using blitting](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/blitting.html)

The code from that example is below.

The sample code runs and displays the plot briefly, but then the plot disappears during the plt.pause(1.0) call. The axis lines and tick marks etc remain.

Running in the loop, you see the plot flashing briefly on, and then erased until the next loop iteration.

What change is needed to keep the plot visible until the loop restarts?

Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# animated=True tells matplotlib to only draw the artist when we
# explicitly request it
(ln,) = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), animated=True)

# make sure the window is raised, but the script keeps going
plt.show(block=False)

# stop to admire our empty window axes and ensure it is rendered at
# least once.
#
# We need to fully draw the figure at its final size on the screen
# before we continue on so that :
#  a) we have the correctly sized and drawn background to grab
#  b) we have a cached renderer so that ``ax.draw_artist`` works
# so we spin the event loop to let the backend process any pending operations
plt.pause(0.1)

# get copy of entire figure (everything inside fig.bbox) sans animated artist
bg = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(fig.bbox)
# draw the animated artist, this uses a cached renderer
ax.draw_artist(ln)
# show the result to the screen, this pushes the updated RGBA buffer from the
# renderer to the GUI framework so you can see it
fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)

for j in range(100):
    # reset the background back in the canvas state, screen unchanged
    fig.canvas.restore_region(bg)
    # update the artist, neither the canvas state nor the screen have changed
    ln.set_ydata(np.sin(x + (j / 100) * np.pi))
    # re-render the artist, updating the canvas state, but not the screen
    ax.draw_artist(ln)
    # copy the image to the GUI state, but screen might not be changed yet
    fig.canvas.blit(fig.bbox)
    # flush any pending GUI events, re-painting the screen if needed
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
    # you can put a pause in if you want to slow things down
    plt.pause(1.0)
```